# No line-in audio option in Arch Linux

Tags: gnome, audio

I have a Dell Latitude 3540 laptop with a single audio jack that does headphone/Line-in/Mic-in. When I connect line-out from an amplifier in Windows, it gives me all the three options. But under Arch Linux + Gnome, when I insert any jack into the port, it gives me these options - Headphone/Headset/Mic-in. In other words, no Line-in.

How can I get Line-in facility in Linux, under Gnome?